# SQL fetching latest result without a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fetching certain item information with the below query:

```
select inventory.itemnum, item.description, invcost.avgcost, invtrans.physcnt
from inventory
    join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
    join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum
    join invtrans on inventory.itemnum = invtrans.itemnum
where inventory.location = 'A'
    and invcost.location = 'A' and invtrans.transdate like '%2015%'
    and invtrans.transtype = 'PCOUNTADJ'
    and invtrans.storeloc = 'A';
```

The query is currently returning only one record for each item and it's using the first record in the INVTRANS table based on the current year (e.g. 2015). This became an issue when there are multiple INVTRANS records with type 'PCOUNTADJ' in that year.

How can I use only the latest (max(transdate)) instead?

I'm aware I could use a sub query like so:

```
...invtrans.transdate = (select max(transdate) from INVTRANS where...)
```

But then I would have to repeat the join with INVENTORY and I've lost the reference to the outer query's itemnum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select inventory.itemnum, item.description, invcost.avgcost, i.physcnt
from inventory 
join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum 
join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum 
cross apply (
   select top 1 physcnt
   from invtrans
   where inventory.itemnum = invtrans.itemnum and 
         invtrans.transdate like '%2015%' and
         invtrans.transtype = 'PCOUNTADJ' and 
         invtrans.storeloc = 'A'
   order by transdate desc) AS i(physcnt)    
where inventory.location = 'A' and invcost.location = 'A';
```

In case of multiple `INVTRANS` records with type `'PCOUNTADJ'` in year `2015`, `CROSS APPLY` returns the one having the most recent transdate.

An alternative approach involves window functions:

```
select itemnum, description, avgcost, physcnt
from (
  select inventory.itemnum, item.description, 
         invcost.avgcost, invtrans.physcnt,
         row_number() over (partition by invtrans.itemnum 
                            order by invtrans.transdate desc) as rn
  from inventory 
  join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum 
  join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum 
  join invtrans on inventory.itemnum = invtrans.itemnum
  where inventory.location = 'A' and invcost.location = 'A' and 
        invtrans.transdate like '%2015%' and 
        invtrans.transtype = 'PCOUNTADJ' and 
        invtrans.storeloc = 'A' ) as t
where t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` in the above query returns `1` for the *most recent* row per `itemnum`.

Comment: This really cleared things up for me, thanks for the in-depth answer and explanations